# Add response header to every handler without repeating the same line

Tags: go, handler

I am writing a small website and for every page, I am putting a server name to its header:

```
func httpSignUp(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    rw.Header().Set("Server", SERVER_NAME)
}
```

I am wondering if there's a way that I can set http.ResponseWriter's default server name, so I don't have to use the same line over and over?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a wrapper to set the header:

```
func wrap(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (
         w.Header().Set("Server", SERVER_NAME)
         h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Wrap individual handlers

```
http.Handle("/path", wrap(aHandler)(
http.Handle("/another/path", wrap(anotherHandler))
```

or the root handler passed to ListenAndServe:

```
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(addr, wrap(rootHandler))
```

Comment: `Server` is a response header, not a request header. I took the liberty to fix that in your code.

Answer (score 3):

> "Prefer composition to inheritance" - [Gang of 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

Inheritance simply wasn't designed into Golang in the first place. ;)

If you are looking for detailed explanations on the *why* part, I believed this has been answered on SO, hence I would just point you to it: [Embedding instead of inheritance in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727250/embedding-instead-of-inheritance-in-go).

Well, you can actually achieve the same result with **adapter design pattern**, which enables you to extend functionality from a built-in library, and to me, its way more flexible than inheritance.

```
func adapter(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Server", SERVER_NAME)
    h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}
```

Or pass in `serverName` as parameter:

```
func adapter(h http.Handler, serverName string) http.Handler {
  return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Server", serverName)
    h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  })
}
```

---

Finally, you have the flexibility to choose which handler(s) to be 'inherited':

```
http.Handle("/path", adapter(your_handler))
```

Or if its meant for every handlers, just 'inherit' to the root-handler:

```
http.ListenAndServe(port, adapter(root_Handler))
```

Comment: `Server` is a response header, not a request header. I took the liberty to fix that in your code.

Answer (score 3):

The `http.ResponseWriter` is an `interface`, not a `struct`. So, You cannot extend it directly. You need to extend the internal `struct`. But it is not idiomatic way to solve this problem.

One approach you can take is to use `middleware`. `middleware` is just a piece of code which will be executed before your main request handler, and can be used perform some common tasks.

For example, to write the same thing using `middleware` approach:

```
func injectServerHeader(handler http.Handler, serverName string) http.Handler {
    ourFunc := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Server", serverName)
        handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(ourFunc)
}
```

This way, you wrap your actual http handler with middleware. So, you won't have to write same code over and over again.

For example:

```
http.Handle("/some-path", injectServerHeader(aHandler))
```